# How to convert GPS degrees, minutes, seconds to degrees, decimal minutes/seconds?

Tags: java, gps

How to convert GPS degrees, minutes, seconds to degrees with ONLY the minutes and seconds converted to decimal??

Comment: Can you be more precise? If I have 15° 30' 45" then you want ... what, 15° 30.75'? Or do you want 15.5125°?

Comment: This question is not precise, show an example

Comment: So you want a  DMS to DM conversion (Integral Degrees and decimal minutes)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple math. `float decimalMinutes = wholeMinutes + ((float)wholeSeconds)/60;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a DMS to DM conversion (DM = Integral Degrees and decimal minutes) –

```
// DMS expressed as d,m and s
int d;
int m;
int s;

// DM excpressed as d, decMin

decMin = m + s / 60.0;
```

Comment: Ok thank you, and I realized I should have just asked about minutes/seconds conversions to begin with...  and I also realized later I need a much different kind of conversion - see my USGS/Google Earth question elsewhere..

Comment: Consider upvoting my answer. (Arrow up)